# Why is this exception being raised? Property [memoryof] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, eloquent

Re: my previous question on relationships.
This:

```
$events = Event::with('memoryof')->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

gets this:

```
{"id":1,"eventTitle":"event 1111","eventDescription":" adaaadad","user_id":1,"is_open":1,"created_at":"2021-08-27T20:45:58.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-08-27T20:45:58.000000Z","memoryof":[]},

{"id":2,"eventTitle":"evt1","eventDescription":"gggggggggggggggg","user_id":1,"is_open":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"memoryof":[
   {"id":1,"user_id":1,"event_id":2,"memTitle":"mem1","   memBody":"kkkkkk","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
   {"id":2,"user_id":1,"event_id":2,"memTitle":"mem2","memBody":"oooo","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]},

{"id":3,"eventTitle":"evt2","eventDescription":"ddddd","user_id":1,"is_open":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"memoryof":[]}]
```

This shows that events 1&3 have no related memoryof and that event id 2 has 2 sets of related data.

So why is this exception popping up: Property [memoryof] does not exist on this collection instance.

--
What is the difference between an amateur and a professional?.
A professional knows how to fix his mistakes.